# how to move a line before on command prompt

Tags: windows, command, prompt

Suppose that i printed three lines on windows command prompt as
hello 1
hello 2
hello 3 using
printf("hello 1\nhello 2\nhello 3"); in c language.I know there is a way to go to the start of line 3 by using \r using c language.But how to move the pointer to the starting of line 1 ie before hello 1.
   Primarily i want to know whether this can be done using 'c' language.
If not,then is there any other way like using other languages.
   I tried ncurses for c,but i want to try on windows command prompt only.

Comment: Are you asking about doing this from the command prompt, or from a C program? Your question is pretty vague and it's unclear what you're asking.

Comment: sorry about that.i am asking is there any way through command prompt despite using any language.

Comment: You have to tell us how you *printed three lines on windows command prompt* before we can tell you if this is possible. Please [edit] your question and make it more clear what you're asking, as I've asked previously.

Comment: You could call [`GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683171%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get the current cursor position; subtract 2 from the `Y` coordinate; and then call [`SetConsoleCursorPosition`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686025%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). The Win32 console API communicates with the console server process, conhost.exe (or csrss.exe prior to Windows 7).